# TypeError: db.collection.remove() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting an error in MongoDB when trying to seed. The Terminal states that db.collection.remove(... is not a function and I cant figure out what is wrong. I have looked on other stack questions as well as the documentation from MongoDB itself on db.collection.remove(). I do have mongo and mongoose installed via NPM...please see my code below.

```
'use strict'

// REQUIRE DB
const db = require('./models');
let tacoList = [
{
    name: "Beef Taco Boats",
    shell: "Hard",
    meat: "Beef",
    spicy: false,
    toppings: "Rice, Beans, Cheese, Avocado, Guac, Pico, Sour Cream, Shredded Lettuce",
    recipe: "http://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/recipes/a53019/beef-taco-boats-recipe/",
    picture: "http://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/recipes/a53019/beef-taco-boats-recipe/?zoomable"
}];

db.Taco.remove({}, (err, taco) => {
    console.log('Removing Tacos');
    db.Taco.create(tacoList, (err,tacos) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('DB Creation Error: ', err);
        }
        console.log('Created Tacos');
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

models file:
tacos.js:

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TacoSchema = new Schema ({
    name: String,
    shell: String,
    meat: String,
    spicy: Boolean,
    toppings: String,
    recipe: String,
    picture: String
});

// Taco Model
const Taco = mongoose.model('Taco', TacoSchema);

// Export
module.export = Taco;
```

index.js file:

```
'use strict'

// Require Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// DB Connect
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
                                process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
                                process.env.MONOGOHQ_URL ||
                                'mongodb://localhost/tacos'
                                );

// EXPORT TACO
module.exports.Taco = require('./tacos.js');
```

Comment: Can you include your models file? seems to me like `Taco` isn't really a collection.

Comment: @jswaldon added